# How to make my headings show up during sort in excel?

Tags: excel

Trying to label my columns as "region" and "date", I have tried - formulas - define name. The column is called region, but it still shows up as Column D when I try to sort. How do I make Sort recognize column D as "region"?

Comment: I know it works if the columns names are in the first row, and you tick the box saying that the first row is special...

Comment: Hey you're absolutely right! Thank you!

Comment: Try using tables.

Answer (score 0):

To develop my comment, as it can help someone else later, the easiest way to name data columns is to put these names in the first rows of the columns.
You can then pick the columns to sort by names if you tick the "My Data Has Headers" check box, and that first row won't be moved by the sort, even if you're sorting text data.
See more details for example at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2449194